# Trigonometry - Addition Theorem Finding Another Trig function

Tags: trigonometry

Using the expansion of
$\sin(A + B)$, prove that $\tan 75^\circ = 2 + \sqrt 3$

Comment: ...please...? And what have you done, tried, thought...?

Comment: Well i have though that -sin might have to be applied since it's asking to find tan? i'm sure i cannot do sin(45 + 30)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember $\tan(\theta)=\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)}=\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\sin(90-\theta)}$ so now we've expressed tan purely in terms of sin. Next you need to think of angles that you know sin of that add (or subtract) to give the desired angle

Comment: simple and good.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

$$\sin 45^\circ=\frac1{\sqrt 2}\;,\;\;\sin 30^\circ=\frac12$$

$$\sin(x+y)=\sin x\cos y+\sin y\cos x$$

Or you may want to use also

$$\tan(x+y)=\frac{\tan x+\tan y}{1-\tan x\tan y}$$

Comment: The question says use the sin Expansion, although that wouldn't give me the tan answer?

Comment: "Expansion", in this case, most probably means what I wrote above. With the values of $\,\sin x\,$ you can also find the values of $\,\cos x\,$ and thus also those of $\,\tan x\,$ . You must know this, else go back to your notes (or even: google it)

Comment: How do i prove that tan 75 = 2 + √3, when they are asking me to use the addition theorem of sine?

Comment: Is it possible that i use the sine expansion, and then, after i find the answer, just add a negative sign in front of it since it's asking me to prove that tan =  2 + √3

Comment: I really have no idea what you mean by "adding a negative sine in fron of the answer (?!!?)" ...and why would you do that to **the answer** ...!

Comment: ok, if it's asking me to find the answer for tan 75? then i would do tan(45 + 30). Although, the question asks to use the sine addition theorem to prove tan. But my question is that if i use sin(45 + 30) then i will get the sin 75 answer. Which the question doesn't seek.

Comment: But you **must** know there's a basic relation between sine and tangent and between since and cosine...!

Comment: sin/cosine = tan ?

Comment: Yes, that one is a basic one...and what about since and cosine, so that you'll deduce cosine by means of sine?

Comment: the fundamental theorem of trig?

Comment: I don't know what is that theorem, but if you write it down perhaps I know it by another name...

Comment: sin^2 x + cos ^ 2 x = 1

Comment: Well, that also;I know it by the name "Trigonometric Pythagoras Theorem". You could also use $\,\cos x=\sin(90-x)\,,\;\;\sin x=\cos(90-x)$ ...

Answer (score 2):

Once you have found $\sin (A+B)$, you can find $\cos (A+B)$ using $\sin^2+\cos^2=1$ (and you know the sign you need for the square root).

Then $\tan (A+B) =\cfrac {\sin (A+B)}{\cos (A+B)}$

Comment: You might be able to see how to prove the formula for $\tan(A+B)$ - which would check your understanding of this situation.